# Set linear velocity on a link of an object using Gazebo messages/topic

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there any way to set linear velocity , collision on a link of an object using messages like Wrench.
That is, publishing on default topics with standalone C++.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20778/set-linear-velocity-on-a-link-of-an-object-using-gazebo-messages/topic/) by [Gaurav](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6898/gaurav/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 9 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> I know the question is about a transport API, but I'll just point out [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=set_velocity&cat=#SettingVelocityonLinks) on several ways of doing it via the C++ API.

There's no transport API for *link velocity*, but there are for:

#### Link force

Publish a wrench message to `~/<model_name>/<link_name>/wrench`, see an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/gazebo/gui/ApplyWrenchDialog.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#ApplyWrenchDialog.cc-631).

#### Joint position / velocity / force

Publish a joint cmd message to `~/<model_name>/joint_cmd`, see an example [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/f4e51e8f64001beda70615ab8982a7d5a4e65b18/gazebo/gui/JointControlWidget.cc?fileviewer=file-view-default#JointControlWidget.cc-604).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1